# Let right div slide in parent div when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sliding

I have two div's (left-right) that I use for drag and drop (HMTL5).
The left-div contains the available members which is a pretty long list. The right div contains the selected members.

The problem here is that the right div is only as high as the number of items in it. So they asked me if I can make the right div slide down when they are scroling down so they can easily drag and drop members from the left to the right and vice versa.

Offcourse the sliding has to be limited to the parent div.

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
}
#left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#right {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bflydesign/odu29g1o/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bflydesign/odu29g1o/ See this updated fiddle...

Comment: So I suppose the left-attribute is counted from the html-border? If I use a big footer on my website the right div will keep following?

Answer (score 2):

```
#right {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  position:fixed;
}
```

The position fixed attribute keeps the div in its place while you scroll therefore it scrolls with the screen

Comment: but in relation to the html and not in relation to the parent div? So if I have still a lot of content under those divs the right div will still follow my scrolling?

Comment: yes as long as it is position fixed. It will follow the scroll no matter what @BFlyDesign Here is a tutorial that will tell you what position is and how to use it : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `position: fixed;` for the right div

Here are the updated CSS:

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 450px;
}
#right {
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```

Updated the fiddle. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/odu29g1o/2/

Comment: Naveed : have you even visited the fiddle link which you have provided ?? Does your fiddle work, have you chekced ??

Comment: The fiddle was working when I provided, but I quit the fiddle without saving, so it did not show you any change. You can use my CSS given above... I am going to update the link in a moment...

Comment: @NaveedButt, you work with fixed widths. Any way to do this with percentages as well? Can u still work with the left-attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the exact thing which you need. Try this out.

Ofcourse you will have to use

```
position: fixed
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yunus_Aslam/rbx4ak1k/

Answer (score 2):

One solution is the following:

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;/*Change to block*/
    position: relative;/*Add position relative*/
    width: 500px;    
}
#left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#right {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;/*Add position fixed*/
    left: 300px;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/odu29g1o/1/)